# Legacy code to create XMLHttpRequest still valid?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

For years I am using the same code snippet to create the `XMLHttpRequest` object:

```
var tReq = (function () {
    var tAn;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        tAn = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) try {
        tAn = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (ex) {
        tAn = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return tAn;
}());
```

I have been using that code for so long that I do not know if it is still up to date.

Does this code still create the `XMLHttpRequest` in every browser or is there a more efficient solution nowadays (***not*** asking for jQuery)?

Comment: I can bet you big money someone's gonna bring up jQuery.

Comment: @David: Haha :) I was explicitly not asking for jQuery :)

Comment: It should still work. You can try it across browsers and see (mostly, IE is the only one the last two are for). So... Eventually you can just get rid of the last two statements once you no longer need to support older versions of IE that don't support `XMLHttpRequest` natively.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Since what version does IE support `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @Amberlamps, IE7 as I remember, though not sure

Comment: The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say IE7; I thought it was IE8.

Comment: So, `XMLHttpRequest` actually works for every browser except IE <= 6?

Comment: That would be an affirmative.

Comment: Thanks, if you would care for an answer, I´d gladly accept.

Comment: @Amberlamps Native `XMLHttpRequest` can be disable though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @RobW - That's an interesting observation (which I incorporated into my answer). Not sure what the thinking is to disable native `XMLHttpRequest` but enable `ActiveX`? Any thoughts on what that might be about?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody suggested defining `tReq` inside an if/else (or re-define on first call) so you don't continue to run if/else each time it's called afterwards.

Comment: @shhac: Good point! I thought creating a new instance on every call was a good idea so the ajax calls would not interfere with each other if they were called with the same instance. Am I wrong?

Comment: jquery is great and does all things. it is good too, as well.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you should consider [AngularJS](http://www.angularjs.org/), which I believe is designed to be a [polyfill](http://www.angularjs.org/).

Comment: @Amberlamps, yes, best to have a new instance every time, but doesn't mean you can't do `var xhr = function(){
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
xhr = function(){return new XMLHttpRequest();}
}else{
xhr = function(){/*whatever*/}
}
return xhr();
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember using this code, some four, five years ago? When the technique first got developed and was still being argued about (anyone remember the *don't disable the back button* argument?), it was still somewhat patchily supported; this would be around Firefox 1/2. If I recall, this originated as an MS Outlook library that was used to make the Outlook client more responsive, and eventually the technique bled over into browsers.

Having said that, the last two lines are legacy; all modern browsers have and do support the plain `XMLHttpRequest`, and the last two were only meant for IE anyhow. In the future, this will perhaps be shortened to `HTTP` or `AsyncRequest` or whatever, but the fact is, unless you need to support IE6, you really only need the first line.

To wit:

> To support versions of Windows Internet Explorer prior to Internet
>   Explorer 7, use the following function to get the XMLHttpRequest
>   object.

```
function getXMLHttpRequest()  {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        }
        catch(ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So, you don't really need it anymore. As Truth says, libraries like jQuery, Angular and their ilk will subsume this into the background over time. But accessing it directly is not a problem either.

Also worth linking to [MSDN's About Native XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), courtesy of RobW's comment under the question. The gist of this is that Group Policy or individual IE policy may disable native `XMLHttpRequest`, so it *may* still be useful to enable `ActiveX` as a workaround, although (at least at this point) it seems a little crayon tinfoil to disable that while *allowing* the much more "problematic" `ActiveX` subsystem. A *possible* explanation of this is bandwidth, concurrent connections or some other network-level concern. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Actually (and I can't believe I'm saying this), jQuery may not be such a bad solution.

In fact, jQuery was invented to sort out browser oddities, it's a form of a massive adapter pattern.

In that sense, jQuery's `.ajax()` method and its aliases are a perfect fit for the job.

As for the solution you currently have, it looks fine to me. Should work for every browser past IE7 (inclusive).

Comment: I agree, but it's not really an answer to whether the code is still valid.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I did mention his code looks fine, but suggested to use a library which normalizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothings wrong with your approach. This is how I would do it though if it helps.

```
var tReq = (function(window) {
    var a = window,
        b = a.XMLHttpRequest,
        c = a.ActiveXObject,

        if (!b && c) {
            try {
                return new c("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                return new c("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        return new b();
})(this);​
```

Comment: Not sure what to say that the MSDN docs show a different string to pass to `ActiveXObject`, for "IE6 support"?

Comment: Alright, I've removed my downvote, although I think you still place too much emphasis on code size.